# Why components are not visible after use paint method to parent

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I created a `JDesktopPane` object as an inner class and I used the `@Override paint` method to `JDesktopPane. after I did it now I could,t add any components to it (Components are not visible). why it isn't work

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JDesktopPane pane = new JDesktopPane(){
            public void paint(Graphics g){
                
            }
        };
        frame.add(pane);

        JInternalFrame inf = new JInternalFrame();
        inf.setVisible(true);
        inf.setSize(100,100);
        pane.add(inf);
    }
}
```

Comment: `paint` is the main method used to paint the component **and its content (children)**. Since not calling the original any more (`super.paint(g)`) the component is not painting itself **or its children**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you should not `@Override` `paint()` method. You should override `paintComponent()` method instead. You should also call `super.paintComponent()` in that method in order to respect the paint chain.

You can find more information about custom painting in Swing's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

I also don't recommend you to extend a `JDesktopPane`. Desktop panes are meant to be [top level containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) that usually stand as host for other components. With other words, keep the `JDesktopPane` just a `JDesktopPane` and then create a JPanel with the overriden `paintComponent()`. Finally, add this panel to the desktop pane.